# *Resolved* Cannot get value from NSUserDefault when in distribution mode

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, objective-c++, ios-app-extension, software-distribution

Recently, I facing a very weird problem with NSUserDefaults and App extension.
I'm using NSUserDefaults to store some value (For example: valueA). And I need to get valueA when open my app via safari.
It work well when I deploy my app directly to device, I can get valueA when I open my app via safari.
But when I archive my app and export to iPA file base on it or push my app to TestFlight, when I open my app via safari, I can 't get valueA anymore.

I guess that the App group of app extension is changed when in distribution, but I can 't know what is the App group when in distribution ? So I'm not sure about that.

I'm just facing this problem recently after I update provisioning of my app.
Does anyone meet this problem before ? Any ideas earn my respect.

Below is the code I use to get and set value with NSUserDefaults

```
#define GROUPID @"group.****"
...
bool NVDataManagerNative::putString(const std::string& key, const std::string& value)
{
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:GROUPID];
    if(ud == nil){
        ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    }
    [ud setObject:convertNSString(value) forKey:convertNSString(key)];
    [ud synchronize];
    return true;
}
...
std::string NVDataManagerNative::getString(const std::string& key, const std::string& def)
{
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:GROUPID];
    if(ud == nil){
        ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    }

    NSString *ret = [ud stringForKey:convertNSString(key)];
    if (nil == ret) {
        return def;
    }

    return [ret UTF8String];
}
```

Comment: For every one meet the problem just like me. This issue was fix just by build and archive it with new MAC PC. I found some other post that recommend to restart MAC instead of. But it not work for me. Anyway, when you meed this problem. You can try 2 above solution.